# Why do they time-travel to the exact same year and month when Judgement Day is about to happen?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, terminator-series, terminator-genisys

What is the reason being they time travel to the exact same year and month when Judgement Day is about to happen?

They could've time travel to 2010 or 2011 or some other previous time when **Genisys/Cyberdyne** was in at development stage. Why go-to a point in time when it is 99% functional and already having 1 billion users pre-ordering it?

Comment: I think that after T2 they changed the theory of time travel and went with multiverse. So they had to stop it from starting as just stopping from creation would result it' creation in later date.

Comment: Okay so why not travel a month earlier? How were they (or you) so sure that destroying it minutes before its launch would prevent its re-creation on a later date?

Comment: If they went too early, may be they had a concern about getting caught. So they may have been decided to go at the best time which gives enough time for whatever the task is and minimize the getting caught possibility

Comment: Because sabotaging it at start would destroy it completely and waste all money. Before they would just gnaw on the whole project that would postpone start. Like putting a stick in the spokes. If the bike is running the whole thing go crumbling down.

Comment: Going too early would just mean a delay.  It would be like postponing the next iPhone because the fingerprint sensor under the screen doesn't work or something.  Its a delay, but not a dealbreaker.  But right before release, then finding out your batteries are no good.  Well, that'll kill a product.

Answer (score -1):

They want to change the chain of events for the sake of getting a particular outcome.  The further back in time they go to change things, the wider the range becomes of potential outcomes.